# How do I pass async method as Action or Func

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a little utility method I use to instantiate my DataContext inside a using statement.  I want to use this with an async method call however, the DataContext is disposed before the method returns.  What is the correct way to use this?

Here is the method (and overload)

```cs
public void Try(Action<IDataServices> method)
{
    using (IDataServices client = GetClient())
    {
        method(client);
    }
}

public TResult Try<TResult>(Func<IDataServices, TResult> method)
{
    using (IDataServices client = GetClient())
    {
        return (TResult)method(client);
    }
}
```

Here is how I am currently using it (fails):

```cs
Model m = await ClientResolver.Try(async x => await x.GetModelByIDAsync(modelID));
```

Reference:
[Calling asynchronous method in using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431528/calling-asynchronous-method-in-using-statement)

Comment: Your `Try` should take a `Task`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You miss the `Task<TResult>` return type:

```
public async Task<TResult> Try<TResult>(Func<IDataServices, Task<TResult>> method)
{
    using (IDataServices client = GetClient())
    {
        return (TResult)await method(client)
    }
}
```