# How can I simplify this method

Tags: c#, async-await

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28814267/how-do-i-pass-async-method-as-action-or-func) I asked how to make a utility method I use awaitable.  The answer to my question is this:

```
    public async Task<TResult> TryAsync<TResult>(Func<IDataServices, Task<TResult>> method)
    {
        using (IDataServices client = GetClient())
        {
            return await method(client);
        }
    }
```

The above is called like this:

```
Model m = await ClientResolver.TryAsync(async x => await x.GetModelByIDAsync(modelID));
```

Just looking at this contraption makes me wonder how it could possibly be efficient.  I am awaiting three times here to save myself the trouble of writing a using statement.  Is there a better way, perhaps passing IAwaitable?  I use this construct quite frequently so I think a bit of optimization will go a long way.  I am far down the road in using async await in my app and I'm really starting to think the tail is wagging the dog.  But that is a story for another day.

Comment: Note my question has nothing to do with TPL.

Comment: *so I think a bit of optimization will go a long way* Whay do you mean by that? Did you benchmark your code and found this as the bottleneck? Or is this simply a gut feeling that something can be improved? If it's the latter, i'd say let this code be, as i don't see anything *wrong* with it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov  Just gut feel.  I just use it a lot so if I can find a little savings it will be helpful.  Async / await is still sleight of hand to me as I mentioned.

Comment: Do you use this function in a bottleneck? What *are* the run time characteristics *exactly*?   Which part of that function takes the most time, and how will that improve your application?  Is your application noticeably slowed down    by this function?  if you can't answer those then your gut feeling is probably off.  That's not to say that one cannot make performance assumptions without profiling. If I need to constantly search a collection for a specific value then I'm probably better off with a B-tree than an array.  Your perceived need, however, seems dubious.

Comment: >> Your perceived need, however, seems dubious.  Oh the irony. LMAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get away with just

```
Model m = await ClientResolver.TryAsync(x => x.GetModelByIDAsync(modelID));
```

Your `TryAsync` method already has `await` in it. I think if you wanted to optimize it you need to profile it and see where the problems are. One possible optimization might be to reuse the client across a class.

You can also avoid switching to the main context by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `TryAsync` which can help but the performance gain will be very minor.

```
public async Task<TResult> TryAsync<TResult>(Func<IDataServices, Task<TResult>> method)
{
    using (IDataServices client = GetClient())
    {
        return await method(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```