# Async within using in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-2017, c#-6.0

I'm developing an application on 'VisualStudio 2017', 'C# 6.0', 'R#'. In `C# 6.0` was introduced new feature - support `async/await' within`try/cath'. i use `using` operator (which is really `try/finaly` under the hood), but i still receive warning `Access to disposed closure`. But really *msGet* shouldn't not be disposed before `DownloadToStreamAsync`.

- Does it can really access disposed variable?
- Is it `R#` glitch?

my code:

```
using( var msGet = new MemoryStream() )
{
    var stopwatchAp = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var stopwatchPureDownload = new Stopwatch();
    var times = new long[ 201 ];
    var retryCount = -1;
    await this._ap.Do( () =>
    {
        stopwatchPureDownload.Restart();
        var downloadToStreamAsync = blob.DownloadToStreamAsync( msGet );
        downloadToStreamAsync.ContinueWith( t => times[ ++retryCount ] = stopwatchPureDownload.ElapsedMilliseconds );
        return downloadToStreamAsync;
    } ).ConfigureAwait( false );
}
```

**Update 1**
I have seen similar questions before:

[Access to disposed closure in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620430/access-to-disposed-closure-in-c)
(but example here doesn't contains `await`, it is not about 'async/await')

[Calling asynchronous method in using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431528/calling-asynchronous-method-in-using-statement) .
(the answer says - use`await`. But as you can see my code contains `await`- but i still have the warning )

Also these questions dated to 2013 year. There was no C# 6.0 in 2013 year. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Please post the code not the image, this is a bad practice

Comment: wasn't it possible to await stuff inside the try block, prior to c# 7?

Comment: Please post your code. This normally happens because you will be accessing the disposed object in `async/await` approach.

Comment: @Alex it was possible to await inside try block, but was not possible to await inside catch or finally blocks (prior to C# 6). So that is not really relevant to this question.

Comment: Also, VS2017 is probably going to be using C# 7, not 6.

Comment: As for the question - Resharper is just not smart enough to recognize captured `msSet` will not be disposed yet when async block runs. It just sees that you captured and use some variable which is later disposed (not related to async at all).

Comment: From user3873265 :Is it the same? Just put you problem terms into search line and you'll get like [Access to disposed closure in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620430/access-to-disposed-closure-in-c) or [Calling asynchronous method in using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431528/calling-asynchronous-method-in-using-statement)

Comment: The date of the original posts is irrelevant. The situation is the same. The language *doesn't* introduce breaking changes like this

Comment: Besides - what does `Do` do? Who says that it executes the lambda *before* returning? There is no guarantee that `msGet` will be available when the code actually executes. `Do` may be storing it for later execution.

Comment: @Evk you *assume* that `Do` executes the lambda instead of storing it for execution after 1 hour. Without actually knowing what `Do` does, you can't be certain. You can argue that Resharper should know since it has access to `Do`'s source.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is true, but the same holds when you just pass that variable as argument to some method, without any lambdas (and no warnings are produced in this case). Anyway, maybe this warning is fine as it is, even though it often produces false positives.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what C#6 actually brought here. Your code has no try/catch block so we're only talking about async/await here which was introduced in C# 5 (with .Net Framework 4.5) in 2013

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Answering to your question `Do` executes lambda. Thanks for interesitng idea about storing lambda

Comment: @DavidG my code contains 'try/catch'. Using will be compiled to 'try/catch'

'The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object)'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have updated question, do you still think it is duplicate?

Comment: Is this question about some error or just ReSharper warning? This should be made clear in your question.

Comment: @Euphoric look to my question again, there are 2 questions. One of them 'is it R# issue?' another 'is it real issue?'

Comment: The duplicate answers that already. There is nothing different in this case. This isn't about await. It's about capturing a variable that points to an object that may get disposed. If this was a blocking method but you stored the lambda into a field for later execution, you'd end up with a disposed object.  `await ` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Do` method takes a `Func<Task>`, inside the invocation where you provide this, you include reference to `msGet`, this is a closure, and the compiler will turn this into a field that is accessed from your `Func<Task>`.

Resharper cannot be sure that your usage of the `Func<Task>` is within the scope or the lifetime of the `using` block, you could for example inside the `Do` method, copy the func into a field and call it again later.

If you are executing the `Func<Task>` immediately inside of `Do` you can safely ignore the warning with:

```
// ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure
```

Comment: Thank you =) Glad I could help. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it has resolved your query.