# SendAsync fails when automatically when removing await from the Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, httpclient

I have this working login code:

```
 using (StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
 {
     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
     //populate the request
     request.Content = stringContent;
     try
     {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client
         .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
         .ConfigureAwait(false))
       {
          response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
          _lastRespose = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          return _lastRespose;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { ... }
```

This works great.
I want to make this code run asynchronously.
So I changed it to get a Task and used ContinueWith to get a call back when the call completes

```
 private async void OnTestLoginCallCompleate(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
 {
     if (response.IsFaulted)
     {
         ShowErrorMessage();
         return;
     }
 }

    private void Login(Action<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> loginCallback)
    {
        _username = userNameTB.Text;
        _password = pwTB.Text;
        _url = urlTB.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(_password) ||
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(_url))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("All fields must not be empty", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri(_url),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        };

        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        String payload = "{ \"email\": \"" + _username + "\", \"password\": \"" + _password + "\" }";

        using (StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            request.Content = stringContent;
            client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ContinueWith(loginCallback);
        }
    }
```

The callback works but I always get `response.IsFaulted` true.
Why is that?

Comment: "I want to make this code run asynchronously." -> the code *is* running asynchronously.  You don't show enough code to help you, but you should look at the Exception property

Comment: You should probably be aware that `await` is effectively a conditional application of `ContinueWith` with syntactic sugar to make it look more like conventional sequential code. It's unclear what introducing the `ContinueWith` explicitly is meant to achieve.

Comment: What does the errormessage say?

Comment: Most probably the `StringContent` is disposed prematurely and you get an `ObjectDisposedException`. Try passing the exception to your `ShowErrorMessage` method (`ShowErrorMessage(response.Exception.InnerException)`), so that you can observe/display the error message.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I don't want to pause the UI thread to make this call but rather continue the execution of the function and get a callback once there is a result

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I updated the question to have the full code

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - you seem to be on the right track. I never noticed that there is an inner exception... Anyway, it is of type ObjectDisposedException and yes it says "Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'. It's probably because of the "Using..." I'll check...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - yes that was the problem. I haven't used many IDsposable objects and missed the obvious. If you post as a separate answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @ItamarKerbel You *don't* pause the UI thread when you use async/await, that's one of the main reasons for using it. It seems to me you have an XY problem here

Comment: It seems to me you just need `private async void Login`

Comment: Thanks Itamar, but the solution is a bit too trivial for an answer IMHO. You could post an answer yourself if you want, or maybe mark your question as duplicate of this: [Calling asynchronous method in using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431528/calling-asynchronous-method-in-using-statement)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the problem comes from the fact that I wrap the async call with `using`.
This disposes of the HttpResponseMessage and when it arrives at the callback it's already disposed of.
The solution will be to remove the `using` and manually dispose of the HttpResponseMessage in the callback.

```
private async void OnTestLoginCallCompleate(Task<HttpResponseMessage> response)
 {
     if (response.IsFaulted)
     {
         ShowErrorMessage();
         return;
     }
     HttpResponseMessage result = response.Result;
    ......code....
     result.Dispose();
 }
```

remove the using part and get:

```
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Content = stringContent;
client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ContinueWith(loginCallback);
```

Answer (score -2):

By looking at code, particularly this part:

```
using (StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
{
   request.Content = stringContent;
   client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ContinueWith(OnTestLoginCallCompleate);
}
```

you need to add await to `client.SendAsync` so that the continuation works properly.

If you try to modify the code as follows, it should work. I have tested locally on my machine (with slight modification so it Runs okay).

```
using (StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
{
   request.Content = stringContent;
   await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ContinueWith(OnTestLoginCallCompleate);
}
```

Comment: I know this already. I'm trying to make the code run async and not sync....

Comment: @Itamar Kerbel adding await will not make your call sync but it will make sure it’s async and the Main thread is not blocked and receive more login calls. If you skip await then you will always get the task is faulted in the continuation chain, since it depends on the result of previous task. I hope it makes things a bit clear.

Comment: This is not correct. You will get the task but it hasn't executed yet. The conitnue with will only get executed once the first task is done. See the comments above for the solution